# I want my PC to turn on automatically when power is connected

Tags: power

I want my PC to turn on automatically when power is connected.
This is not for turning on after a power loss but so when I remote control the power socket the pc can be turned on from a distance  without someone being needed to press the power button.

Edit: I do not want to resume previous power state, my reasoning for doing this is so that my raspberry pi controlled extension lead can both turn on the mains and turn on my pc (without the raspberry pi being connected to the power switch on the pc) so that from there I can remote desktop to my pc.
All the research I did on this only came up with resuming power state, I couldn't find any other information 
Wake On Lan is also a possibility and is another way I could turn on the PC from the raspberry pi, but not the solution I want.

Comment: Have you looked into Wake-On-LAN?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question shows little research effort. It reads like an order being placed for us to complete for you. This is a Q&A site. Please read [ask], then update your post with details and a specific question.

Comment: **Not** a good idea: if you can turn power *on* with at the socket, then you can turn it *off*, possibly during disk I/O. As long as you perform a shutdown (*not* sleep), and wait for it to complete, there would be no problem, but if you frequently turn the mains off, there is risk of human error.

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: If wake-on-lan is not easy, you can use a second remote controled power (5V output) socket to power a relay whose output pins are connected to your motherboard's POWERON pins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I m giving  many options  how to switch on your pc the method that suits you and solve your need you can opt and try them

It depends on motherboard features if it new and ACPI COMPLIANT then it may support powering on the computer with a PS/2 keyboard. when the power to a computer is off, there remains a small amount of electrical current through CMOS Battery in some of the circuits on the motherboard.

**First method**

Motherboard with an ACPI compliant BIOS , a PS/2 keyboard can be used to power on the computer .  describing the steps below and giving the link of videos below

1. Turn on the computer  with smps power switch and pushing the on of switch and press the "Delete" or "F2" key as soon as you see the POST boot  screen till BIOS menu screen appears.
2. Press arrow keys on  keyboard to navigate to  "Advanced" or "Advanced Settings" or " Power management" menu option. Press the "Enter" .
3. Press arrow key and go to the "Power Management" or "ACPI Management" option. Press the "Enter" key and then move the select to the "Wake on Keyboard" or "Power on by Keyboard" option or "turn on"
4. Press "+" or "-" key to change the "Wake on Keyboard" or "Power on by Keyboard"  or " turned on"  option value setting to "Enabled."
5. Press the "F10" key to save the BIOS setting changes and exit the BIOS. The computer will restart.
6. If not restart then Press the power button on the computer and hold it for four or five seconds. The computer powers off.
7. Press any key on the keyboard. The computer should start without the need to push the power button.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=r5ELvDL8wyA

**Second Method**

If its not work and their is no option of  power management through keyboard or any other option then u  have to shot the power switch with jumper or keep the wire if power button outer shorted
Follow the steps

1. Open your cabinet case
2. On the motherboard locate the  front panel pins connectors.
3. Ensure the 24-pin and 4/8-pin power headers are connected to the motherboard.
4. Ensure all other necessary power headers are connected to corresponding devices.
5. Locate the power switch header for the front panel connectors on the board.
6. These are normally labeled “PWR_SW,” “PWR_BTN,” etc. I
7. no cable is connected to the positive and negative headers. Ensure the PSU is switched on and plugged in.
8. For confirming and testing pins.Find a screwdriver. Bridge the two pins allocated to the power button. The system should turn on.
9. Now put a jumper to the power pins. And disconnect the power plug and again switch on if computer is switched then OK if not then step 10
10. Some old motherboards work on with shorting pins but some have new boards restarts reboots on shorting then u can do is two things
    Cut or disconnect the wire  from power switch side and then  connect it with some external switch which shorts it for 2 sec and leave it automatically available in electronic shop or u can. Find online or u can manipulate power switch of case if possible

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4lz-p5SKi0

**THIRD METHOD**

This method is for remotely switching on the Computer through MOBILE or  LAN network  it can be done through bios and  application softwares in windows but dont know about raspberry for details refer to the following links if it works and suits you

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/turn-pc-android-phone-wakeonlan/

https://www.howtogeek.com/192642/how-to-remotely-turn-on-your-pc-over-the-internet/

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-remotely-turn-on-computer-from-lan-and-wan/

https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-does-Wake-on-LAN-WOL-with-TeamViewer-work/ta-p/33

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/shut-down-pc-with-android-phone/

https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/shut-down-pc-with-android-phone/

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/smartphones/how-to-turn-your-mobile-phone-into-a-pc-remote-control/

https://www.online-tech-tips.com/smartphones/remotely-access-a-pc-or-mac-from-a-smartphone-or-tablet/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VG6sCC4afRI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pDjjMO3az84

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdkwS0vkvGA

> hope my answer will help you if any of the option work do tell me in comment which one worked for you and if not fell free to ask more queries and if it worked do not forget to upvote and accept my answer

Comment: @MátéJuhász i have described 2 methods 1 from keyboard and other from shoting the power pins in  front panel connector yah i have seen the  question that they want to remotely  on the pc for  remotely switching i m finding composing  the solution and will add 3rd method soon

Comment: @MátéJuhász i have answered all options  they can try as per their  comfort and usage and need  and will be useful for other users readers

Comment: The "First method" using option in UEFI is really bad on modern mainboard (MSI in my case). From connecting power to PC to real start (power on signal sent to PSU) it takes ~12 seconds. I use a switchable extension lead and this delay is really annoying. The "Second Option" eliminates the possibility to force a shut down by pressing power for ~4 seconds. Isn't there a better way to do this on hardware level?

Comment: the problem with BIOS auto power on is if your CMOS battery dies, this setting is lost; jumping the power switch on the motherboard is the best option IMO

Comment: great answer! you really went above and beyond! (lots of consumer PC does not have the super easy BIOS feature. so your answers are really ingenious and creative.)

Answer (score 6):

There is often an option in the BIOS settings to always turn on with AC power is resumed.  This is useful for servers, but it is not always present on OEM systems, from my experience.

Answer (score 3):

As said above, have a look through your BIOS settings. Most servers and a lot of desktops have an option to turn on when the power is turned on. I know mine does. You usually have the option to "do nothing", "resume previous state" or "turn on" or something like that.